# How to use Xcode certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate

I've developed an app for my company that I'm about to submit to Apple. We've purchased the 99$ developer license and been approved by Apple. Now the thing I want to know is : what should I do before submitting the app in the Apple Developer Portal (iTunes Connect) ? I've been told about using a certificate in Xcode to sign my apps but how to do this ? Is there anything else ?

Thanks a lot for your advices. I'm almost done..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the great tutorial by **RayWenderlich** guys for 
step by step description for

> How to sign and publish your app on iTunes Store

check below links may help you

[Part one](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8003/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-1) and
[Part two](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2)

if you get any trouble let me know i have done this!!

Answer (score 2):

## Certificates are essential!!

It's a security hazard, so only signed and approved code can run on iOS devices (or most other platforms for that matter).  Getting a cert is easy (actually, certs, seeing as you need a developer and a distribution certificate), and an excellent tutorial may be found [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/).

Comment: Thanks a lot too. Yeah I know it was compulsory, and as I don't live in an English-speaking country we only have few documentation, so sometimes it's kinda hard to do what I want. But thanks again !

Comment: Yes, of course.  Just remember that, and life as a developer gets a whole lot easier.  I'm surprised you haven't heard about certificates though... They're required to test an app on a a physical device.

Comment: That's just what I'm going to do. I'm done with developing my app, I only tried it with the simulator for weeks, now wait and see !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like reading, you can always watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XVO0tIHmQTg) short video. You will always need a provisioning profile when deploying to the app store. An provisioning profile is:

> A provisioning profile is a collection of digital entities that
>   uniquely ties developers and devices to an authorized iPhone
>   Development Team and enables a device to be used for testing. A
>   Development Provisioning Profile must be installed on each device on
>   which you wish to run your application code. Each Development
>   Provisioning Profile will contain a set of iPhone Development
>   Certificates, Unique Device Identifiers and an App ID. Devices
>   specified within the provisioning profile can be used for testing only
>   by those individuals whose iPhone Development Certificates are
>   included in the profile. A single device can contain multiple
>   provisioning profiles.

You can also check Apple's documents in the [Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/ProvisioningPortal_Recipes/_index.html).